# Chunk processing in Spring Batch effectively limits you to one step?

Tags: jdbc, spring-batch

I am writing a Spring Batch application to do the following: There is an input table (PostgreSQL DB) to which someone continually adds rows - that is basically work items being added. For each of these rows, I need to fetch more data from another DB, do some processing, and then do an output transaction which can be multiple SQL queries touching multiple tables (this needs to be one transaction for consistency reasons).

Now, the part between the input and output should be a modular - it already has 3-4 logically separated things, and in future there would be more. This flow need not be linear - what processing is done next can be dependent on the result of previous. In short, this is basically like the flow you can setup using steps inside a job.

My main problem is this: Normally a single chunk processing step has both ItemReader and ItemWriter, i.e., input to output in a single step. So, should I include all the processing steps as part of a single ItemProcessor? How would I make a single ItemProcessor a stateful workflow in itself?

The other option is to make each step a Tasklet implementation, and write two tasklets myself to behave as ItemReader and ItemWriter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My first thought is that this isn't a batch application, but I may be wrong. It doesn't sound like there's any start or stop to the process, and there certainly don't seem to be any parameters that you can use to define a 'job'. This sounds like a straightforward Java app. Any particular reason you're looking at Spring Batch?

Comment: How would you do it as a 'straightforward Java app'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer - yes you are effectively limited to a single step. But:

1) For linear workflows, you can "chain" itemprocessors - that is create a composite itemprocessor to which you can provide all the itemprocessors which do actual work through applicationContext.xml. Composite itemprocessor just runs them one by one. This is what I'm doing right now.

2) You can always create the internal subflow as a seperate spring batch workflow and call it through code in an itemprocessor similar to composite itemprocessor above. I might move to this in the future.